# Datatables.js - hyperlink from URL JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have some JSON sample data, which has a URL object. When I add the data into a datatable, I am getting the URL as text, instead of a link.

```
var items = [    
    {
    "Alert": "Alpha",
    "Date": "23/04/2021",
    "Information": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a ultrices nisl, ac interdum libero. Vestibulum ac convallis mauris, auctor hendrerit augue. Vivamus elementum sapien eget dui maximus, quis laoreet magna pulvinar. Sed feugiat hendrerit est, et tincidunt lorem pellentesque nec. Quisque consequat laoreet eros in porta.",
    "Name": "Tester",
    "Status": "Live",
    "URL": "https://www.google.com/",
    "Updated": "21/04/2021 09:35"
}
]
```

Datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
$('#thisTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": items,
    columns: [
        { title: "Date", "mDataProp": "Date" },
        { title: "Status", "mDataProp": "Status" },
        { title: "Alert", "mDataProp": "Alert" }, 
        { title: "Updated", "mDataProp": "Updated"},
        { title: "Name", "mDataProp": "Name" },
        { title: "Information", "mDataProp": "Information" },
        { title: "URL", "mDataProp": "URL"}      
    ],     
}); 
});
```

I have read through the documentation, which references assigning a function to pick up the URL, however when I include the below I am just getting a console error. First time trying to use datatables with a JSON source, which is a little more complex.

```
"data": "URL",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<a href=" + URL +">LINK</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The code to build your link HTML needs to be changed. Right now, you are just building a single string surrounded by `'`:

```
return '<a href=" + URL +">LINK</a>';
```

So, the variable name in that string is not treated as a variable. It's just taken literally as a piece of text.

Instead, use this:

```
return '<a href="' + data + '">LINK</a>';
```

(The use of `data` instead of `URL` is explained below).

2. You can combine your column renderer into your URL column definition. And you can use the render function's `data` variable (see below).

There is a 3rd (optional) update - which is to replace the older variable names (for example `aaData`) with their newer versions (`data`). You can see a listing of these old and new names [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).

Combining all of the above points gives this:

```
$('#thisTable').dataTable({
    "data": items,
    columns: [
        { title: "Date", data: "Date" },
        { title: "Status", data: "Status" },
        { title: "Alert", data: "Alert" }, 
        { title: "Updated", data: "Updated"},
        { title: "Name", data: "Name" },
        { title: "Information", data: "Information" },
        { 
          title: "URL", 
          data: "URL",
          render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return '<a href="' + data + '">LINK</a>';
          }
        }      
    ]
});
```

In the URL column I use `data: "URL"` to assign the URL value to a variable called `data`, which DataTables then uses in the render function.

Comment: Thank you. Was trying all kinds of variations. Didn't realise that I should have also included title with the Url section. Your help was greatly appreciated.